# how to set column format in sheet JS

Tags: angular, types

i'm trying to create an xlsx using sheetJS with spesific column  that all cells including empty ones as text.
i'm using json_to_sheet....

i managed to set all cell with content as format cell ass text but the empty ones are set to "general"
is there a way to find the spesific cloumn and is there a way to set the column?

```
downloadExcelFile(data: any[], sheetName: string, header?: string[], filename: string = "export") {
let workbook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
let worksheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(data, { header: header });
let mifiImsiColumn = XLSX.utils.decode_col("AF"); // 1
let mifiMsisdnColumn = XLSX.utils.decode_col("AG"); // 1
let fmt = '@'; // or '"$"#,##0.00_);[Red]\\("$"#,##0.00\\)' or any Excel number format


/* get worksheet range */
let range = XLSX.utils.decode_range(worksheet['!ref']);
for ( let i = range.s.r + 1; i <= range.e.r; ++i) {
  /* find the data cell (range.s.r + 1 skips the header row of the worksheet) */

  let ref = XLSX.utils.encode_cell({r: i , c: mifiMsisdnColumn});
  let ref1 = XLSX.utils.encode_cell({r: i , c: mifiImsiColumn});

  /* if the particular row did not contain data for the column, the cell will not be generated */
  if (!worksheet[ref] && !worksheet[ref1] ) { continue; }
  /* `.t == "n"` for number cells */
  if (worksheet[ref].t !== 'n'  && worksheet[ref1].t !== 'n' ) {

    worksheet[ref].z = fmt;
    worksheet[ref1].z = fmt; }

}

workbook.SheetNames.push(sheetName);
workbook.Sheets[sheetName] = worksheet;



const wbout = XLSX.write(workbook, {bookType: 'xlsx', bookSST: false, type: 'binary'});


/* the saveAs call downloads a file on the local machine */
FileSaver.saveAs(new Blob([this.s2ab(wbout)], {type: 'application/octet-stream'}), `${filename}.xlsx`);
```

}

thank you for all your help ..

Answer (score 1):

It can be done using excel js plugin. Use `ws.getCell('A1').numFmt = '0.00%'` to mark a column number type Percentage.
For more info please refer https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs#number-formats